# Positive, negative part of a filtration

Tags: measure-theory, filtrations

Let $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$ be a filtration and let $\mathcal{G}_{t} = \mathcal{F}_{t+}$. Now, I want to prove that $\mathcal{G}_{t-} = \mathcal{F}_{t-}$ for $t>0$.

I am quite new to filtrations, but the definition of a filtration is not helping me any further in proving the above statement. So, I can use some of your help.

A filtrations is defined as a collection of $\sigma$-fields $\{\mathcal{F}_t:t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}\}$ that satisfy $\mathcal{F}_s \subset \mathcal{F}_t \subset \mathcal{F}$ for all $0<t<\infty$.

Given a filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$, define the $\sigma$-algebras
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}_{t+} = \bigcap_{s:s>t} \mathcal{F}_s.
\end{align}
$\{\mathcal{F}_{t+}\}$ is a new filtration, we say $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$ is *right-continuous*. Under the assumption that the filtration is right-continuous, we want to show that $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$ is *left-continuous* aswel. Therefore, I can image that we will look at an the union instead of the intersection of $\sigma$-algebras. However, the exact approach is for me still unclear.

Therefore, we define *left*-*continuity* by
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}_{t-} = \sigma \bigg( \bigcup_{s:s<t} \mathcal{F}_s \bigg).
\end{align}
Since the union of $\sigma$-fields is not necessarily a $\sigma$-field, $\mathcal{F}_{t-}$ needs to be defined as the $\sigma$-field generated by the unions of of $\mathcal{F}_s$ over $0 < s <t$.

So, now it should be trivial (why exactly?) that,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}_{t-} = \sigma \bigg( \bigcup_{s:s<t} \mathcal{F}_s \bigg) \subseteq \bigcup_{s:s<t} \bigcap_{k:k>s} \mathcal{F}_k = \mathcal{G}_{t-}.
\end{align}
And how to find the other inclusion?

Comment: The title makes one wonder whether you know the definition of $\mathcal{F}_{t+}$ and $\mathcal{F}_{t-}$ for $t>0$. Recalling these would be a plus for the question (and would rather immediately suggest an approach, I should add).

Comment: Correct! In the meanwhile I am more comfortable with filtrations and the corresponding definitions. However, I would greatly appreciate your help to show the above statement.

Comment: Right, now one inclusion is obvious. Can you write down precisely the other, desired, inclusion?

Comment: The inclusions we want to find are $\mathcal{G}_{t-} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{t-}$ and $\mathcal{F}_{t-} \subseteq \mathcal{G}_{t-}$. However, to write down precisely the desired inclusions, I need to know what the exact definition is of $\mathcal{F}_{t-}$. Is it the union of $s:s < t$, which is exactly the opposite of $\mathcal{F}_{t+}$. If so, I find it hard to interpret this definition. Google does not provide any answer for the exact definition of $\mathcal{F}_{t-}$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Indeed it seems necessary to add a definition of $\mathcal F_{t-}$ to your question. Note that, as mentioned before, every sensible definition makes one of the inclusions $\mathcal F_{t-}\subset\mathcal G_{t-}$ or $\mathcal G_{t-}\subset\mathcal F_{t-}$ obvious. Did you fathom which one?

Comment: If my definition of $\mathcal{F}_{t-}$ is correct, I think I do fathom that $\mathcal{G}_{t-} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{t-}$. How to find the other inclusion?

Comment: My first definition was correct, except the $\sigma$ in front of the union over $s<t$. And, I understand why $\mathcal{F}_{t-} \subseteq \mathcal{G}_{t-}$ instead of $\mathcal{G}_{t-} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{t-}$

Comment: Retweet @Did, can you help me out?

Comment: First of all, your post is extremely confused (which might explain why you fail to see why the obvious is obvious). Note for example that no, we do not say that $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$ is right-continuous simply because we previously had the idea of defining $\{\mathcal{F}_{t+}\}$. Rather, we say that $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$ is right-continuous *if and only if* $\mathcal{F}_{t+}=\mathcal{F}_t$ for every $t\geqslant0$. Likewise, $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$ is left-continuous *if and only if* $\mathcal{F}_{t-}=\mathcal{F}_t$ for every $t>0$. ...

Comment: ... Now to your question: you consider $\mathcal{G}_{t} = \mathcal{F}_{t+}$ for every $t\geqslant0$ and your aim is to prove that $\mathcal{G}_{t-} = \mathcal{F}_{t-}$ for every $t>0$. Note first that, *by definition*, $\mathcal F_s\subseteq\mathcal G_s$ for every $t>s\geqslant0$ hence $\bigcup\limits_{s:s<t}\mathcal F_s\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{s:s<t}\mathcal G_s$ and $\mathcal F_{t-}=\sigma\left(\bigcup\limits_{s:s<t}\mathcal F_s\right)\subseteq\sigma\left(\bigcup\limits_{s:s<t}\mathcal G_s\right)\subseteq\mathcal G_{t—}$ for every $t>0$. ...

Comment: ... Likewise, again *by definition*, $\mathcal{G}_{s} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{t-}$ for every $t>s\geqslant0$ hence $\bigcup\limits_{s:s<t}\mathcal{G}_{s} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{t-}$ hence $\mathcal{G}_{t-} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{t-}$ for every $t>0$. And now, the real question is what in this was impossible to write down under the condition that one paused to write down the definitions involved?